# How may absurdism be relevant in our current world and recent events, such as the pandemic?

Tags: camus, absurdism

The mundanity and gloominess of lockdown would have caused many people to come face to face with the absurd and become very confused and lost. What would accepting and embracing the absurd, and continuing in spite of it look like in present day?

For context, I am a high school student
writing an essay for my philosophy class.
Apologies if my question is not worded very well, english is not my first language.

Comment: See [Albert Camus' Absurdist Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/camus/#HapFacOneFat): if he can decide to continue the struggle of life in spite of 20th Century terrible events (Holocaust), for sure the same applies to 21th...

Comment: Camus and Nietzsche would probably say it's your own responsibility to make your life interesting. We have to take responsability for our own boredom. During the lockdown I decided to learn guitar and I had a blast.

Answer (score 3):

One of Camus' most famous works is a novel called The Plague, which is about a disease outbreak. I would suggest taking a look into that, as there are plenty of straightforward comparisons that can be made to the current pandemic, and plenty of resources available for analyzing it from an absurdist perspective.